# How to handle this kind of timeseries

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series

I am using Python and I have a sample dataset of this kind:

```
columns = ['product_id', 'market_value2015', 'market_value2016', 
           'market_value2017', 'market_value2018', 'market_value2019', 
           'market_value2020', 'market_value2021', 'retired'],
```

where `market_value2015...2021` are `floats` and retired is a `Boolean`.

The objective is to train a neural network that predicts if a product will be retired or not.

Initially, my idea was to use floats variables from 2015 to 2020 in order to predict retirement in 2021 by considering these variables as time series, but I got stucked since I've never seen a dataset like this before. So, I don't know how to let the neural network understand that floats variables have the concept of time from 2015 to 2020, since they are always on the same level. I hope that this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

From a model point of view, there is no "time" concept.

What you are trying to do is to use a feature vector $x_t$, for $t$ ranging from 2015 to 2020 (why not 2021 as well?).

This is not a problem of time series forecast, but rather a time series (binary) classification. Each example is a time series, with an outcome retired or not.

Comment: So I'm not able to use Recurrent Neural Networks, right? In your opinion which model should I use? @Oscar

Comment: You can use RNN to encode your input time series but the aim of the model is to predict 1 element (the label) for each time series. In the same way you predict the class of an iris flower for each 4-feature vector. Just for instance, have a look at https://developer.ibm.com/learningpaths/get-started-time-series-classification-api/

Comment: Ok thanks. So just for clarity, there is no concept of "sequence of more rows" because each row is different in meaning from each other. But each row is still a time series of 7 features (value_2015 to value_2021), right?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. However, maybe I found a way to transform the dataset in order to introduce the concept of sequences and so the concept of time, but I would like to know your opinion first.
This is the result of the transformation with the shape of the data structures reported https://ibb.co/8YJk2Bz .
So in practice I create sequences of shape (9, 1) with a step of 9 (the entire sequence) each time, to differentiate the product and make each sequence different from others. The first layer of the network is an LSTM layer with an input shape of (None, 9, 1) in this case. Can it work?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying formatting the experiment this way?

'product_id' | 'Year' | 'market_value' | 'retired'

01222        | 2015   | 20.0           | Yes

01222        | 2016   | 19.0           | Yes

01222        | 2017   | 18.0           | Yes

01222        | 2018   | 17.0           | Yes

.               .       .                 .

.               .       .                 .

01222        | 2021   | 12.0           | Yes

Alternatively, a retired product must have experienced deterioration over the years. Thus assuming a linear pattern of deterioration starting 2015 until 2021 :

'product_id' | slope | y-intercept | 'retired'

01222       |  2    |  0          | Yes

Furthermore, this data is "Panel data", a short time series per unique productid , not a regular time series problem. On that account, do not introduce the product id column at all to the neural network or ML when using that representation. You don't want it to treat every product separately! Instead, replace it with an integer value if possible, perhaps some product specifications.

Finally, probably RNNs will not be most useful for this short panel data, perhaps CNNs (they can capture longitudinal patterns ) or maybe LSTNets.